# How to get values of arrays of exports

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filter

I have the following array that has been generated by the DocuSign API:

```
const signers = [
  exports {
    email: 'email1@gmail.com',
    name: 'Test Name One',
    recipientId: 'signer_1',
    routingOrder: '1'
  },
  exports {
    email: 'email2@gmail.com',
    name: 'Test Name Two',
    recipientId: 'signer_2',
    routingOrder: '2'
  },
  exports {
    email: 'email3@gmail.com',
    name: 'Test Name Three',
    recipientId: 'signer_3',
    routingOrder: '3'
  }
]
```

I need to get the index of the object in this array where the recipientId === 'signer_2' (for example), and have tried the following:

```
const signerKey = signers.filter(signerObj => {
  console.log(signerObj) // returns "exports { ...email, name, etc }"
  console.log(Object.keys[signerObj]) // returns undefined
  console.log(signerObj.exports.recipientId) // returns undefined
  console.log(typeof signerObj) // returns object
  return signerObj.recipientId === 'signer_2' // returns undefined
})
```

How do I deal with finding data within these `exports` since they're not actual objects?

Comment: are you sure of the object format? it seems like it has syntax error

Comment: Yes, it's being generated by: docusign.Signer.constructFromObject({
      name: 'Test Name One',
      email: 'email1@gmail.com',
      recipientId: 'signer_1',
      routingOrder: '1',
    });

Comment: Have you tried using the lo-dash framework? You could formulate it like this: _.findIndex(signers, function(obj) {
  return obj.recipientId === 'signer_2';
});

Comment: @casenonsensitive Thank you! I ended up using the solution below but will try yours if it comes up again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason when I used JSON.stringify() then JSON.parse I was able to process everything normally:

```
const stringified = JSON.stringify(signers)
const signersObject = JSON.parse(stringified)
```

@casenonsensitive recommended using the lo-dash framework, which I haven't looked into yet, but could be a better solution.